# Database naming convention (ISO, RFC, etc.) for tables, columns, triggers, constraint, primary and foreign keys

Tags: database

Who knows a naming convention **(ISO, RFC o something like that)** for tables, columns, triggers, constraints, primary and foreign keys to create a database in any database system (mysql, sql server, oracle, etc..).

For example i see databases with this naming conventions:

Naming Convention 1:
**Table Name:** Foo
**Columns:** Name, Description, IsEnabled

Naming Convention 2:
**Table Name:** foo
**Columns:** name, description, isenabled

Naming Convention 3:
**Table Name:** foo
**Columns:** name, description, is_enabled

Naming Convetion 4:
**Table Name:** Foo
**Columns:** FooName, FooDescription, FooIsEnabled

But i not find any **ISO or RFC** for this naming conventions or anothers naming conventions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Pick one. Stick to it.

Answer (score 1):

The best benchmark is togo with the default microsoft basic database:
https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/releases/tag/adventureworks

in your case the naming convention should be CamelCase would be the perfect example, therefore go with the number 4:

Naming Convetion 4: Table Name: Foo Columns: FooName, FooDescription, FooIsEnabled

and stick to it as Mitch says :)